# Beginner: L1 Parsing Table Syntax Error

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm a CS Student working on a code to implement but having hard time running it.

Can you please help me out in running this L1 Parsing Table.

May be i'm doing some stupid syntax mistake.

I'll be very thankful to your replies.

Cheers!

```
    #include <iostream.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void main()
    {
        clrscr();
        int i=0,j=0,k=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,o1=0,var=0,l=0,f=0,c=0,f1=0;
        char     str[30],str1[40]="E",temp[20],temp1[20],temp2[20],tt[20],t3[20];
        strcpy(temp1,'\0');
        strcpy(temp2,'\0');
        char t[10];
        char array[6][5][10] = {
                     "NT", "<id>","+","*",";",
                     "E", "Te","Error","Error","Error",
                     "e", "Error","+Te","Error","\0",
                     "T", "Vt","Error","Error","Error",
                     "t", "Error","\0","*Vt","\0",
                     "V", "<id>","Error","Error","Error"
                      };
        cout << "\n\tLL(1)  PARSER  TABLE \n";
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                cout.setf(ios::right);
                cout.width(10);
                cout<<array[i][j];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\n\tENTER THE STRING :";
        gets(str);
        if(str[strlen(str)-1] != ';')
        {
              cout << "END OF STRING MARKER SHOULD BE ';'";
              getch();
              exit(1);
        }
        cout << "\n\tCHECKING VALIDATION OF THE STRING ";
        cout <<"\n\t" << str1;
        i=0;

    while(i<strlen(str))
        {
         again:
              if(str[i] == ' ' && i<strlen(str))
              {
                   cout << "\n\tSPACES IS NOT ALLOWED IN SOURSE STRING ";
                   getch();
                   exit(1);
              }
              temp[k]=str[i];
              temp[k+1]='\0';
              f1=0;
         again1:
              if(i>=strlen(str))
              {
                   getch();
                   exit(1);
              }
              for(int l=1;l<=4;l++)
              {
                if(strcmp(temp,array[0][l])==0)
                {
                    f1=1;
                    m=0,o=0,var=0,o1=0;
                    strcpy(temp1,'\0');
                    strcpy(temp2,'\0');
                    int len=strlen(str1);
                    while(m<strlen(str1) && m<strlen(str))
                    {
                          if(str1[m]==str[m])
                          {
                               var=m+1;
                               temp2[o1]=str1[m];
                               m++;
                               o1++;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                               if((m+1)<strlen(str1))
                               {
                                   m++;
                                   temp1[o]=str1[m];
                                   o++;
                               }
                               else
                                   m++;
                          }

                    }
                    temp2[o1] = '\0';
                    temp1[o] = '\0';
                    t[0] = str1[var];
                    t[1] = '\0';
                    for(n=1;n<=5;n++)
                    {
                        if(strcmp(array[n][0],t)==0)
                            break;
                    }
                    strcpy(str1,temp2);
                    strcat(str1,array[n][l]);
                    strcat(str1,temp1);
                    cout << "\n\t" <<str1;
                    getch();

                    if(strcmp(array[n][l],'\0')==0)
                    {
                        if(i==(strlen(str)-1))
                        {
                              int len=strlen(str1);
                              str1[len-1]='\0';
                              cout << "\n\t"<<str1;
                              cout << "\n\n\tENTERED STRING IS                             VALID";
                              getch();
                              exit(1);
                          }
                          strcpy(temp1,'\0');
                          strcpy(temp2,'\0');
                          strcpy(t,'\0');
                          goto again1;
                    }
                    if(strcmp(array[n][l],"Error")==0)
                    {
                          cout << "\n\tERROR IN YOUR SOURCE STRING";
                          getch();
                          exit(1);
                    }
                    strcpy(tt,'\0');
                    strcpy(tt,array[n][l]);
                    strcpy(t3,'\0');
                    f=0;
                    for(c=0;c<strlen(tt);c++)
                    {
                         t3[c]=tt[c];
                         t3[c+1]='\0';
                         if(strcmp(t3,temp)==0)
                         {
                               f=0;
                               break;
                         }
                         else
                               f=1;
                     }

                     if(f==0)
                     {
                        strcpy(temp,'\0');
                        strcpy(temp1,'\0');
                        strcpy(temp2,'\0');
                        strcpy(t,'\0');
                        i++;
                        k=0;
                        goto again;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        strcpy(temp1,'\0');
                        strcpy(temp2,'\0');
                        strcpy(t,'\0');
                        goto again1;
                    }
                }
              }
              i++;
              k++;
        }
        if(f1==0)
               cout << "\nENTERED STRING IS INVALID";
        else
              cout << "\n\n\tENTERED STRING IS VALID";
        getch();
    }
```

OUTPUT

---

```
        LL(1)  PARSER  TABLE

        NT      <id>         +         *         ;
        E        Te     Error     Error     Error
        e     Error       +Te     Error
        T        Vt     Error     Error     Error
        t     Error                 *Vt
        V      <id>     Error     Error     Error

        ENTER THE STRING :<id>+<id>*<id>;

    CHECKING VALIDATION OF THE STRING
                E
                Te
                Vte
                <id>te
                <id>e
                <id>+Te
                <id>+Vte
                <id>+<id>te
                <id>+<id>*Vte
                <id>+<id>*<id>te
                <id>+<id>*<id>e
                <id>+<id>*<id>
                ENTERED STRING IS VALID
    [/Code]
```

Comment: What specifically is your question? You have a lot of uncommented code, a grammar, and a parse table, so I'm not sure what specifically you'd like us to look at.

Comment: `iostream.h` is not a standard header. `conio.h` is completely unnecessary. The other headers you include are all deprecated. `main` must return `int`. The C strings should be replaced with `std::string`. `gets` has been removed from both C and C++ recently because it's terrible (use `std::getline`). `exit(1)` can and should be `return EXIT_FAILURE;`. The `goto`s should be loops. Overall, you shouldn't be squishing everything into one function. I'm sure the `goto`s will naturally disappear given separate functions that reduce `main` into a clear flow pattern.

Comment: This question should be migrated to CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: Actually `conio.h` is necessary because `clrscr()` is declared in that header file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, You can make a `clrscr` function using proper Windows API functions (or I imagine a cross-platform library would have one) instead of DOS functions, but it's still pretty unnecessary to clear the console at the beginning anyway. If the user wants to do that, they can use `cls & prog.exe`. If using the winapi approach, Microsoft actually has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022(v=vs.85).aspx) for it so you can at least see the pattern of functions to use.

Comment: @chris, all I'm saying is that if you remove the `conio.h` header without removing the `clrscr` function the program won't compile.  If the program is run on Linux, Windows API won't work.  Also, many platforms don't have screens, such as the embedded system I'm working on (it has a serial port connected to a terminal).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, If you run the program on Linux, `conio.h` won't work :) Anyway, I see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want a code inspection / code review.  Here it goes:

**C++ vs. C**
Your program looks like it is C, but your question tag says C++.  So, I'll view it from the C++ perspective.

Switch your header files to C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Note there is no ".h" suffix in the header names.

**Console I/O**
The `conio.h` header file is compiler specific.  You didn't mention which compiler you are using, so many of us can't load your source and help you.

The `clrscr()` function is not necessary and often times, clearing the screen erases information that you may need later.  BTW, it is not portable because not all platforms have screens.

**void main**
The `main` function returns `int`, always.

**Variable Names**
The C++ language specification allows for at least 32 characters in an identifier.  More characters are allowed but only the first 32 are used to determine duplicates.

So use them.  Single letters only reduce your typing time.  Descriptive names allow other people, and you, to easily understand how your code is working.  Do you know what all of those variable are used for, without reading any other documentation?

**Style -- one declaration per line**
Declare one variable per line.  Easier to maintain, easier to read.

**Spaces?**
Spaces cost very little build time and don't effect execution speed.  They add clarity, use them.
The general rules are one space between variables and operators; one space after a comma.

**Character Arrays**
Don't use them, the cause problems.  Since your question is tagged C++, use `std::string` instead.

**strcpy for one character**
Don't use `strcpy` for one character, just assign it directly:

```
  temp1[0] = '\0';
```

By the way, `strcpy` is dangerous, use strncpy instead; notice the letter 'n'.

**Const**
Use it.  Things that don't change should be declared as `const` to prevent mistakes and allowing the compiler to find this mistakes.  Also, character constants (a.k.a. literals) are constant and can't be changed.

**Mapping Tables**
Three dimensions?  Really?
How about something easier to understand, such as a table of structures:

```
struct Token_Entry
{
  const char * token_text;
  unsigned int token_ID;
};

const Token_Entry token_table[] =
{
  {TOKEN_NT, "NT"},
  {TOKEN_ID, "<id>"},
  {TOKEN_PLUS, "+"},
  // ...
};
const unsigned int Number_Of_Token_Entries =
    sizeof(token_table) / sizeof(token_table[0]);
```

**Avoid gets, it's dangerous.**
The `gets` reads input regardless of quantity.  If you allocate 5 slots and the User types 10 letters, you will overrun your buffer.  Very bad.
Use `fgets` if you must or switch to C++ and use `getline(std::string)`.

**Avoid the `exit` function**
The proper technique is to use `return` in the `main` function.  This allows proper clean up of variables.  The `exit` function is a little bit more dangerous.

**No Gotos and labels**
Read up on loops in your favorite, correct, C++ text.  Expecially the `break` and `continue` keywords.

**One assignment per line**
Carriage returns, linefeeds and newlines are free, use them.  One assignment per line.  It slows down the compilation process by either microseconds or nanoseconds; in otherwords, the time required to process line ending characters is negligible.

**Use parenthesis**
Grouping logical statements with parenthesis may not be necessary if you have memorized the precedence table, but they make the code more readable:

```
  while ((m < strlen(str1)) && (m < strlen(str)))
```

**Compute constants once**
For example, the length of the string will not change during your analyzing loops.  So store it into a constant variable:

```
const unsigned int length_str1 = str1.length(); // Since you will be using std::string.
const unsigned int length_str  = strlen(str);   // Or if you insist on C-style strings.
while ((m < length_str1) && (m < length_str))
```

**Unsigned vs. signed integers**
One of my pet peeves.  Use `int` (a.k.a. `signed int`) if the value can be negative; otherwise use `unsigned int`.  For example, a text length can't be negative.  What does a string of length -5 look like?

**Comment your code**
Tell the reader what you are doing and why.  Don't talk about assigning variables.  For example, why is `k` incremented at the end of the loop?  Why are you setting `temp` to null in one section but not the other.  What is the `f1` variable used for?  Set verbosity = maximum.

**Use a debugger**
Since you didn't comment the code, used single letter variable names, your code will take a lot of time to understand.  You can help out by **using a debugger**.  A debugger allows you to execute lines one at a time (a.k.a. single stepping), and print out or display the values in your variables.  A lot faster than the ancient art of adding print statements for your variables at different locations in your code.

Also, using a debugger is a faster method to test and evaluate your program than posting it on the web, especially here.

Comment: The Program now runs with no error but when I'm trying to add the following code, it just shows multiple erorrs, can you help?

Comment: I wanted to output the following table: http://i.imgur.com/YHdYU5y.jpg @Thomas-Matthews

Comment: @MuzammilM.Rafiq: Is your issue with the language, or lexical analysis?  As far as printing the table goes, one needs to know how the table is organized.  You'll have to be more specific.  Have you used a debugger?  Can you use a `for` loop?  Do you know how to access fields in a structure?

Comment: What I wanted to print is the table for the LL1 Parsing upon string validation, the code after editing works fine by now, but I don't know how to use the code in C++ to print the table upon string validation (The Last part of the code as you see). What I wanted is to run this code in a manner that is shows up LL1 table upon string validation. I hope you get it now, this is my assignment goal to achieve, and I'm in urgency actually to get it to submission dept by tomorrow.

Comment: Using two `for` loops:  `for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {printf("    %10s", array[i][j]);} printf("\n");}` You may have to change the order of loops.  This is what I mean by "can you use a for loop"?  You should consider re-taking the C or C++ class, before you move on to more difficult assignments.